# Menu doesn't want to open when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

***Problem***

when you click on the button (in your browser, not in codepen) the menu will not open

***Desidered behaviour***

The Menu has to open when you click on the burger button.

***Code***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var burger = $('.btn');
  var menu = $('.full-menu');
  var navItems =$('.nav__item');

  burger.click(function(){
    burger.toggleClass('btn--open');
    menu.toggleClass('menu--open');
  });

  navItems.hover(function(){
    navItems.not($(this)).toggleClass('nav__item--hover');
  });
});
```

This is my html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FlexBox Exercise #2 - Responsive Menu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button class="btn">
      <span class="btn__line"></span>
      <span class="btn__line"></span>
      <span class="btn__line"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="full-menu">
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav__list">
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              Portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              Contacts
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="title">FlexBox Exercise #2 - Responsive Menu</h1>
    </div>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i was trying to work on that and understand it, but i noticed that the menu doesn't open in chrome and edge. Yeah, in codepen works, but in my browser(chrome and edge) i see only the animation of the burger.

***Codepen***

[pen here](https://codepen.io/veronicadev/pen/BxomWa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using jQuery library.

Use it:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i');

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

body{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.circle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 95px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #f0efef;
}


.title {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  background-color:transparent;
  border:0;
  padding:0px;
  z-index:1;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.btn__line{
  height:2px;
  width:32px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#292929;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

.btn__line:nth-child(1){
  left:-4px;
}
.btn__line:nth-child(2){
  left:4px;
}
.btn__line:nth-child(3){
  left:-4px;
}


.btn__line + .btn__line{
  margin-top:6px;
}

.btn:hover .btn__line, .btn--open .btn__line{
  left:0px;
}

.btn--open .btn__line{
  background-color:#fff;
}

.nav__list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    visibilty: hidden;
    transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

.nav__item--hover{
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.full-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
    width: 100%;
  height:0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
  -moz-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
  -ms-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
  -o-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
}

.full-menu:before, .full-menu:after{
  content: '';
  height: 0;
   position: fixed;
  top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

.full-menu:before{
  z-index: -2;
  background-color:#3b3b3b;
    transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
} 

.full-menu:after{
   z-index: -1;
  background-color:#121212;
    transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
  -moz-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
  -ms-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
  -o-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) ;
}



.menu--open:before, .menu--open:after{
  height: 100%;
}

.menu--open:before{
    transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -webkit-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -moz-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -ms-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -o-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
} 

.menu--open:after{
    transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
}

.menu--open{
  height:100%;
  transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
}

.nav__item {
    padding: 0 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
}

.menu--open .nav__item{
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu--open .nav__list{
  visibilty: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.3s;
}

.nav__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav__item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    
}
.nav__item:hover .nav__link{
  font-weight:700;
}

.nav__item-not-hover{
  opacity:0.3;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .nav__list{
    flex-direction:column;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .nav__item{
    padding:8px 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .nav__link{
    font-size:26px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FlexBox Exercise #2 - Responsive Menu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button class="btn">
      <span class="btn__line"></span>
      <span class="btn__line"></span>
      <span class="btn__line"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="full-menu">
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav__list">
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              Portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              Contacts
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="title">FlexBox Exercise #2 - Responsive Menu</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var burger = $('.btn');
  var menu = $('.full-menu');
  var navItems =$('.nav__item');
  
  burger.click(function(){
    burger.toggleClass('btn--open');
    menu.toggleClass('menu--open');
  });
  
  navItems.hover(function(){
    navItems.not($(this)).toggleClass('nav__item--hover');
  });
});

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't tell you how many of my bugs were "stupid errors". Don't feel bad about them, just learn from them. Also, when doing web development, always have DevTools open. It can save you a lot of head ache.

Answer (score 3):

> Yeah, in codepen works, but in my browser(chrome and edge)

In codepen jQuery in included in settings, but in your standalone code jQuery is not included.

Next time check the codepen settings and browser console for errors.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I bet if you open the **Chrome DevTools** (F12) you will see this error in the console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

This is because you are trying to use **jQuery** without including it. 
Add this to your html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure to place it above where you are including your `script.js` file.